# UHD video sample in 4:4:4

Tags: software-recommendation

For my project I need to find or short video (1 min) of a UHD video in 4:4:4
I coudn't find any thanks to google.
I am now considering making one from 4 full HD stream in 4:4:4 but I don't know what tools I could use.

And by the way, although I read it's possible to make a full HD 4:4:4 stream from a 4K 4:2:0 I didn't find any sample available.

Any advice?

Comment: What's the use case for the sample?

Comment: Encoding evaluation

Comment: Will a synthetic video do, like an animated mandelbrot fractal?

Comment: So is the problem finding a Ffmpeg command-line to create uhd 444 video or finding a hi-res video sample? There is a lot of sample footage of all different cameras floating around on the Web I.e. Arri Alexa:https://www.arri.com/DE/camera/alexa/learn/alexa_sample_footage/

Comment: @Mulvya yes a synthetic video will be fine

Comment: @HansMeiser The problem is finding a uhd 444 video to test encoders performances. So, either creating a synthetic one, or just downloading it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, to generate some synthetic videos in the required size and pixel format:

#### Mandelbrot fractal

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=24" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 5 mb444.mov
```

This will generate a `5` second UHD video @ 24 fps. You can experiment with the various parameters detailed [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#mandelbrot), such as coloring methods or amount of zoom.

There's also filters to generate patterns as per Conway's Game of [Life](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#life) or a custom [cellular automaton](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#cellauto), although those will be very 'noisy' with default settings.

You can also use a [test pattern](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) as a source:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "testsrc=s=3840x2160:r=24" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 5 test444.mov
```